# Trying to get SUM but I need to filter out all negative numbers and put them in a seperate column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using this code to get a sum of prices but there will also be negative numbers in this column that i will not want to be part of the equation at this point. What's the best way to filter those numebers out?

```
ISNULL (SUM(CAST(JC11.SALE_PRICE1 AS MONEY)) OVER(PARTITION BY JC11.JOB_NUMB),
    SUM(CAST(OE11.SALE_PRICE1 AS MONEY)) OVER(PARTITION BY OE11.ORD_NUMB)) AS REVENUE



SELECT DISTINCT
    CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATEADD(d, CU10.DAT_CREATED +5843, 0), 1)AS 'DATE ENTERED'
    ,CU10.CUST_NAME 
    ,CU10.INDUSTRY_CODE
    ,JC17.IND_DESC
    ,COUNT(JC10.JOB_NUMB) OVER(PARTITION BY JC10.JOB_NUMB) AS JOB_TOTAL
    ,COUNT(OE10.ORD_NUMB) OVER(PARTITION BY OE10.ORD_NUMB) AS ORDER_TOTAL 

    ,ISNULL(JC10.JOB_NUMB,
    OE10.ORD_NUMB) AS 'JOB/ORDER'

    ,ISNULL ((SELECT TOP 1 JC10.DATE_SHIPPED FROM JC10 WHERE JC10.BILLTO_NUMB = CU10.BILLTO_NUMB ORDER BY JC10.DATE_SHIPPED DESC), 
    (SELECT TOP 1 OE10.DATE_SHIPPED FROM OE10 WHERE OE10.BILLTO_NUMB = CU10.BILLTO_NUMB ORDER BY OE10.DATE_SHIPPED DESC)) AS DATE_SHIPPED

    ,ISNULL (SUM(CAST(JC11.SALE_PRICE1 AS MONEY)) OVER(PARTITION BY JC11.JOB_NUMB),
    SUM(CAST(OE11.SALE_PRICE1 AS MONEY)) OVER(PARTITION BY OE11.ORD_NUMB)) AS REVENUE

    ,(SELECT DISTINCT SUM(CAST(JC21.ACTUAL_DLR AS MONEY)) OVER(PARTITION BY JC21.JOB_NUMB) FROM JC21 WHERE JC21.JOB_NUMB = OE10.ORD_NUMB OR JC21.JOB_NUMB = JC10.JOB_NUMB AND (CAST(JC21.ACTUAL_HRS AS MONEY) > 0.00 )) AS LABOR_COSTS

    ,(SELECT DISTINCT SUM(CAST(JC20.TOT_COSTS AS MONEY)) OVER(PARTITION BY JC20.JOB_NUMB) FROM JC20 WHERE JC20.JOB_NUMB = OE10.ORD_NUMB OR JC20.JOB_NUMB = JC10.JOB_NUMB )
    + ISNULL((SELECT DISTINCT SUM(CAST(JC21.ACTUAL_DLR AS MONEY)) OVER(PARTITION BY JC21.JOB_NUMB) FROM JC21 WHERE JC21.JOB_NUMB = OE10.ORD_NUMB OR JC21.JOB_NUMB = JC10.JOB_NUMB AND (CAST(JC21.ACTUAL_HRS AS MONEY) > 0.00 )),0) AS TOTAL_COSTS

    ,(ISNULL (SUM(CAST(JC11.SALE_PRICE1 AS MONEY)) OVER(PARTITION BY JC11.JOB_NUMB),
    SUM(CAST(OE11.SALE_PRICE1 AS MONEY)) OVER(PARTITION BY OE11.ORD_NUMB))) - (SELECT DISTINCT SUM(CAST(JC20.TOT_COSTS AS MONEY)) OVER(PARTITION BY JC20.JOB_NUMB) FROM JC20 WHERE JC20.JOB_NUMB = OE10.ORD_NUMB OR JC20.JOB_NUMB = JC10.JOB_NUMB )
    - ISNULL((SELECT DISTINCT SUM(CAST(JC21.ACTUAL_DLR AS MONEY)) OVER(PARTITION BY JC21.JOB_NUMB) FROM JC21 WHERE JC21.JOB_NUMB = OE10.ORD_NUMB OR JC21.JOB_NUMB = JC10.JOB_NUMB AND (CAST(JC21.ACTUAL_HRS AS MONEY) > 0.00 )),0)  AS PROFIT

    --,(SELECT SUM(CAST (JC11.SALE_PRICE1 AS MONEY)) OVER(PARTITION BY JC11.JOB_NUMB) FROM JC11 WHERE CAST(JC11.SALE_PRICE1 AS MONEY) < 0.00)
    --,(SELECT TOP 1 JC10.DATE_SHIPPED FROM JC10 WHERE JC10.BILLTO_NUMB = CU10.BILLTO_NUMB ORDER BY JC10.DATE_SHIPPED DESC) AS LAST_JOB_SHIPPED_DATE
    --,(SELECT TOP 1 OE10.DATE_SHIPPED FROM OE10 WHERE OE10.BILLTO_NUMB = CU10.BILLTO_NUMB ORDER BY OE10.DATE_SHIPPED DESC) AS LAST_ORDER_SHIPPED_DATE
    --,SUM(CAST(JC11.SALE_PRICE1 AS MONEY)) OVER(PARTITION BY JC11.JOB_NUMB) AS JC_REVENUE
    --,SUM(CAST(OE11.SALE_PRICE1 AS MONEY)) OVER(PARTITION BY OE11.ORD_NUMB) AS OE_REVENUE
    --,JC10.JOB_NUMB
    --,OE10.ORD_NUMB


FROM CU10
    JOIN JC17 AS JC17 ON JC17.CODE = CU10.INDUSTRY_CODE
    LEFT OUTER JOIN JC10 AS JC10 ON JC10.BILLTO_NUMB = CU10.BILLTO_NUMB
    LEFT OUTER JOIN OE10 AS OE10 ON OE10.BILLTO_NUMB = CU10.BILLTO_NUMB
    LEFT OUTER JOIN JC11 AS JC11 ON JC11.JOB_NUMB = JC10.JOB_NUMB
    LEFT OUTER JOIN OE11 AS OE11 ON OE11.ORD_NUMB = OE10.ORD_NUMB






WHERE
    CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATEADD(d, CU10.DAT_CREATED +5843, 0), 112) > 20150101 
    AND (JC10.JOB_SHIPPED_FLAG = 'Y' OR OE10.ORD_SHIPPED_FLAG = 'Y')
```

Comment: Can you pls add all your query, from, where etc... to make a better answer.

Comment: You can put a `CASE` statement inside the `SUM`: `SUM(CASE WHEN JC11.SALE_PRICE1 >= 0 THEN CAST(JC11.SALE_PRICE1 AS MONEY) END) OVER ...`. The CASE will return null for any less than zero, which will cause them to be ignored by the SUM.

Comment: Why do you have to cast SALE_PRICE1 as money? Are you storing this in a character based field?

Comment: @SeanLange
Yes it is being stored as CHAR(10)

Comment: You do realize how ridiculous it is to store numbers in a character datatype? Not only are queries a lot more challenging you lose the ability of proper index usage when you constantly have to cast this to a usable datatype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make make use of a `CASE` statement for this.

```
ISNULL (SUM(CASE WHEN JC11.SALE_PRICE1 >= 0  then CAST(JC11.SALE_PRICE1 AS MONEY) else 0.00 end) OVER(PARTITION BY JC11.JOB_NUMB),
    SUM(CASE WHEN OE11.SALE_PRICE1 >= 0  then CAST(OE11.SALE_PRICE1 AS MONEY) else 0.00 end) OVER(PARTITION BY OE11.ORD_NUMB)) AS REVENUE
```

Comment: Doing this will then give me zero's for my OE11.Sale_price1 fields. But if use NULL then my isnull works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the rest of the query is doing.  But something that's like what others have done, but including the negative portion is:

```
ISNULL(
    SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(JC11.SALE_PRICE1 AS MONEY) >=0 THEN CAST(JC11.SALE_PRICE1 AS MONEY) ELSE 0.0 END) OVER(PARTITION BY JC11.JOB_NUMB),
    SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(OE11.SALE_PRICE1 AS MONEY) >=0 THEN CAST(OE11.SALE_PRICE1 AS MONEY) ELSE 0.0 END) OVER(PARTITION BY OE11.ORD_NUMB)
) AS POSITIVE_REVENUE,
ISNULL(
    SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(JC11.SALE_PRICE1 AS MONEY) <=0 THEN CAST(JC11.SALE_PRICE1 AS MONEY) ELSE 0.0 END) OVER(PARTITION BY JC11.JOB_NUMB),
    SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(OE11.SALE_PRICE1 AS MONEY) <=0 THEN CAST(OE11.SALE_PRICE1 AS MONEY) ELSE 0.0 END) OVER(PARTITION BY OE11.ORD_NUMB)
) AS NEGATIVE_REVENUE
```

Without the rest of the query (from, where conditions, etc.) it will be pretty difficult to formulate a real query.

Comment: Ahhh, good ol CASE statement I think that will work great it should also solve another issue I have. Thanks alot